# How to add a library to PHP?

Tags: php, cryptography, pecl, bcmath, mnpp

My version of PHP, 5.3.8, doesn't contain [BC-Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php), which is needed for many cryptocurrency functions.

Google hasn't been particularly helpful for links on how to install this particularly library, so I'm at a total loss on how to add it to my already running PHP webserver.

Might someone point me in the direction of how to install this?

Comment: mac 10.7.5, so linux, right?

Comment: Windows or linux, if linux what distribution?

Comment: Are you *sure* it doesn't contain BC-Math? After checking the docs, it says, `Since PHP 4.0.4, libbcmath is bundled with PHP. You don't need any external libraries for this extension.`

Comment: yeah I can't run any BC-math functions. I get errors like `Call to undefined function bcdiv()`. You get the same thing if you run `bcscale(8);` here=> http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: `$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
tidy
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib
`

Comment: You need to (re)build PHP and supply the config line --enable-bcmath

Comment: I've never built PHP before and a little scared to destroy the version I already have running. Are there some simple commands for this?

Comment: Technically, Mac OS X is based on *BSD, so neither Windows nor GNU/Linux.

Comment: Here's a page that might help you to do what @Tularis suggests: http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/php/ Alternatively, you can install PHP with homebrew.